# Opencv Decode Gray code pattern tutorial 3D scanner Problems

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, gray-code

I used a ready-made tutorial code from the opencv library in C ++, the link is as follows:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/da9/tutorial_decode_graycode_pattern.html

This is the title of this code (Decode Gray code pattern tutorial)
The job of this code is to take photos as a pattern and then read the calibration values ​​from the yaml file and display the photos in the form of points cloud in the 3D scan output. I used his default photos. Also from his yaml files, all of which are at the following address.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/tree/4.x/testdata/cv/structured_light/data

The code is compiled correctly, but the problem is that in the example above it is not written what arguments to give to achieve the desired result. Displays its code output as follows:

[image]

But the code I get is as follows:

[image]

The values ​​that I give the program as an argument are as follows:
`./main images.yml` `calibrationParameters.yml 3 3 0 0`

Please help me to execute the code correctly and bring it to the highest display quality. Can you suggest where exactly I look at the code?

Comment: please post errors / code as TEXT, not as images, thank you !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-decode-gray-code-pattern-tutorial-3d-scanner-problems/9120

Comment: Excuse me, is it wrong to ask a question in two forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct parameters passed to the program should be

```
./main images.yml calibrationParameters.yml 1280 800
```

The parameters 1280 and 800 represent projector's width and height

I found this information in the author's github repo, you can find it [here](https://github.com/RobertaRavanelli/GSoC2015_statue_dataset)

I compile the code in the tutorial and use the parameter above, works great (OpenCV version: 4.5.5)

Comment: Your parameters worked correctly for me. Thank you. The question is how to find the length and width of the projector?

Comment: I believe you can find the parameter on the projector. The length and width are just the resolution of the projector

Comment: Is there a solution to convert the above code into python code?